# PowerBuilder - string to array convert

Tags: arrays, string, powerbuilder

I have string in PowerBuilder:

```
string test_string = "1,2,3,4,5"
```

I want to convert it to array:

```
 string array[] = {'1','2','3','4','5'}
```

How to do that?

// Thanks for help :)

I do that:

```
    string string_to_edit = "1,2,3,4"
    string array[], string_now
    long arraylen, stringlen, place_nbr, i, place_tt

    stringlen = len(string_to_edit)
    DO WHILE  stringlen > 0 
        place_nbr = pos(string_to_edit, ",")
            IF place_nbr > 0 THEN
                place_tt = place_nbr - 1
                string_now = Mid(string_to_edit,0,place_tt)
                string_to_edit = RIGHT(string_to_edit,stringlen - place_nbr)
                stringlen = stringlen - place_nbr
            ELSE
                string_now = string_to_edit
                string_to_edit = RIGHT(string_to_edit,stringlen - place_nbr)
                stringlen = 0
            END IF
        string_now = trim(string_now)
        arraylen = UpperBound(array)
        array[arraylen+1] = string_now
    LOOP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use any gettoken algorithm for strings. Arrays in PB grows automatically. For example

```
string array[]
array[UpperBound(array)+1] = NextToken(test_string,',')
```

Write `NextToken` function yourself, or loop with `Pos(test_string, ',', iFrom)`

Comment: the code snippet here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sybase.public.powerbuilder.powerscript/N5w8Kvi9lo8 uses this approach but may be more cut-and-pasteable

Answer (score 5):

You can get inspiration by looking at the way that it's done in the PFC ( the of_parsetoarray() function) :

https://pfc.svn.codeplex.com/svn/12.0/pfcapsrv/pfc_n_cst_string.sru

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a datawindow with an external datasource consisting of a single text column.

2) Declare a create a datastore and assign the datawindow object from 1 above to it.

3) Use the Importstring method to insert the string into the datastore. This method accepts comma delimited strings (ImportType of CSV!).  It also returns the number of rows inserted.

4) Loop through the rows in the datastore and insert the values into the array.